# Javascript is taking too long to extract a unique array out of a (multiline) string

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have a huge data set that gets loaded in pre tag, like the following.

```
00:00:00 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: sysName = SERVER
00:00:01 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: resultsDirName = github
00:00:02 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Device4Branch = //github/server_manager01/test1
00:00:02 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: testCase = server_manager01
00:00:03 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: timestamp_style = RELATIVE
00:00:04 INFO SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: token = 36
00:00:04 FAIL SERVER-SYSTEM - Cmd Line Arg: Campaign = True
```

There will be around 30,000+ lines and I want to store unique words in an array.
Following are lines of code to fetch data from the div which hold this pre tag data and stores unique words separated by space into an array.

```
pre_data = document.getElementById("data_div").innerHTML.split('\n');
var words = [];
var reg = new RegExp("\\S*", "ig");

for (x = 0; x < pre_data.length; x++) {
   words = words .concat(pre_data[x].match(reg));
}

// To remove null values
filtered_data = words .filter(function (el) {
   return el != ''; });

// Set gives unique data
unique_data = Array.from(new Set(filtered_data ));
```

But this is taking 10+ seconds if there are 30,000+ lines. What could be an effective way to get it faster?

Comment: If you want to do stuff in the background in JavaScript, then look into _Web Workers_.

Comment: A few questions:  (1) What are you trying to achieve with the RegExp? is it to extract all words of all lines? (2) what do you need a JS Set for? (3) Could you please place a few lines of input and your desired output? so it's easier for us to understand what's going on

Comment: I want to populate the autosuggestion box field, so initially, I'm extracting all unique words including special characters like (/,: etc).  from each and every line. So for the given set of lines my desired output should be ['INFO', 'SERVER-SYSTEM', 'Cmd ', 'line',  'sysName', 'resultsDirName', 'github', ...] and so on. With unique repeated data

Comment: But this is consuming a lot of time, so how do I optimize this or can it be done dynamically as we get words in Input Search box where autosuggestion will be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is what you are looking for but this is how I would do it;

- Find the element and get the innerHTML or innerText and split it by newLine which will give you an array
- Reduce the lines and create **one** array of all words of each line

  - Split the line by white space which will give you an array of words
  - Filter out the empty words `w => w`
  - Add the words array to the accumulator and return it
- Now that you have all words you can filter out the duplicated

PS: you don't have to create 3 variables as I did, you can chain the array functions and create one variable if you want

```js
var linesArray = document.getElementById('my-pre').innerHTML.split('\n');
var words = linesArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  return acc.concat(cur.split(' ').filter(w => w));
}, [])

var uniqueWords = words.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
console.log(uniqueWords)
```

```html
  <pre id="my-pre">
    Hello Stackoverflow
    I'm having some issues
    with extracting a unique array
    out of my multiline string
    this is a test to see if
    the the array is unique enough
    this is a test to see if
    the the array is unique enough
    this is a test to see if
    the the array is unique enough
  </pre>
```

Comment: This code works but is taking much longer than my solution. Approximately 3 times more time.

Comment: Then your string must be huge. try to output only the data that matters to yo to the pre tag that you are using. Because if Javascript has issues creating an array out of your string must be huge. do me one favour and run this in your browser console `document.getElementById("data_div").innerHTML.length` what number do you see?

Comment: The number is 22,000+